# Map over an array in React

Tags: reactjs, array-map

I am building an app that displays video games and various info about them, pulling data from an API. I am trying to display all of the platforms that the game is playable on, PlayStation, Xbox, etc. The JSON has an array of platforms for each game that each contain a platform object with a name (that I am trying to display). Maps really confuse me I would really appreciate someone's help with this. I will include a snippet of the JSON.

```json
  "count": 1326,
  "next": "https://api.rawg.io/api/games?key=8d1a421af80b4f9b8650de12d9943010&page=2&search=destiny",
  "previous": null,
  "results": [
    {
      "slug": "destiny",
      "name": "Destiny",
      "playtime": 24,
      "platforms": [
        {
          "platform": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Xbox One",
            "slug": "xbox-one"
          }
        },
        {
          "platform": {
            "id": 18,
            "name": "PlayStation 4",
            "slug": "playstation4"
          }
        },
        {
          "platform": {
            "id": 14,
            "name": "Xbox 360",
            "slug": "xbox360"
          }
        },
        {
          "platform": {
            "id": 16,
            "name": "PlayStation 3",
            "slug": "playstation3"
          }
        }
      ],
```

```
const GameCard = ({
  game: {
    name,
    background_image,
    metacritic,
    released,
    platforms,
    platform,
    esrb_rating,
  },
}) => {
  return (
    <div className="bg-gray-600/30 m-5 p-0 rounded-xl shadow-xl shadow-gray-700 border-solid border-2 border-gray-700 max-w-[640px] hover:scale-105 ease-in duration-300">
      <img
        className="rounded-t-xl h-[360px] w-[640px] border-b-2 border-gray-600"
        alt={name}
        src={
          background_image
            ? background_image
            : "https://via.placeholder.com/640x360"
        }
      />
      <h1 className="text-center text-4xl text-gray-900 tracking-wide font-bold mt-2 font-mono">
        {name}
      </h1>
      <div className="text-gray-800 text-center font-mono py-2">
        {platforms ? platforms.map(() => <span></span>) : null}
```

Comment: Note that JSON is a format for sending data over the wire, like XML. Once you receive the data (via `fetch`, XHR, axios, or whatever), it's likely been parsed to JavaScript and you are no longer dealing with JSON any more. If you were, you'd be dealing with a string.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my terminology.

Comment: You should be able to follow the [Array.prototype.map() documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get this working... The first argument in the map callback is a single `platform` object in your case. Iterating through an array of data is not as intimidating as it seems.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loop through an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp):

> map() creates a new array from calling a function for every array
> element.
>
> map() calls a function once for each element in an array.
>
> map() does not execute the function for empty elements.
>
> map() does not change the original array.

This creates an array of names from an array of platform objects, such as results.platforms in the json snippet you showed.

```
platforms.map(platform => <span>{platform.platform.name}</span>)
```

Comment: Wow so close yet so far thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If you map over the platform after taking that part to the variable called platforms in your code then you can map over it like I shown below:

```html
<div className="text-gray-800 text-center font-mono py-2">
        {platforms ? platforms.map((item) => <span key={item.platform.id}>
          {item.platform.name}
        </span>) : null }
</div>
```

Don't forget to insert the key inside the span tag. Which will act as a unique identifier for each span tag.

reference: [Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)